# REST API of Teamcity for initiate a build

Tags: java, teamcity

Can anybody suggest how TEAMCITY RestAPI can used for trigger a build for a particular project availble in bitbucket/mercurial repository and getting the result of the build ,that is jar/war file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [JetBrains help](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild):

> To start a build, send POST request to
>   http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue with the "build"
>   node in content - the same node as details of a queued build or
>   finished build. The queued build details will be returned.

Set up build configuration as normal, and trigger using REST API with steps above.